# Constraint Layout ListView is moving when keyboard appears

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am making an app which will automatically show contacts and then when a contact is clicked inside a `ListView`, it is directly sent to the `EditText` field. Then they can choose whether to send a message or call the number.

The problem is that when I click on the `EditText`, the `ListView` also gets up which covers the `EditText`, buttons, and the contacts label. I guess it's because of the keyboard of the phone.

**XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/idLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundwallpaper2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contacts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/contacts"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.293" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:inputType=""
        android:labelFor="@+id/number"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.05" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/callBtn"
        android:layout_width="57dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:text="@string/calls"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.729"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.184"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/smallcallbtn" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/idList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="290dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.743"></ListView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_width="57dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.26"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.184"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/smallmsgbtn" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

App's screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Find the activity where you have your code for example **ActivityA** and introduce this line in the **AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<activity
   android:name=".activities.ActivityA"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> 
</activity>
```

[From Android Documentation:](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element)

> "adjustPan"   The activity's main window is not resized to make room for
>   the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are
>   automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by
>   the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is
>   generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to
>   close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of
>   the window.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that the screen should not move the layouts in any case or when the user clicks on editText. You could add windowSoftInputMode to adjustNothing which will not move the layouts. The line will be added in Manifest. Below is the code that would be in your manifest file.

```
<activity android:name=".Activities.Main2Activity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
```

For just testing purpose I have used activity name as MainActivity2 add the android:windowSoftInputMode line in your activity.
Hope that helps.